# I messed up and removed important packages, is there a way to restore all packages that would come with the live distro ?

Tags: apt, package-management, chroot

Im on Ubuntu server 16.04 and I tried to solve some issues by uninstalling and reinstalling. Then i see apt telling me lot of packages are not required and can be autocleaned. I tried to install them back but many things are broken. Can i try to restore all the packages that come with the distro but still keeping all the packages i added uptill now ?

Comment: is more easy to reinstall the OS

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` should pull in everything that is normally installed by default.  There is also `lubuntu-desktop` and so on for the other desktop flavors.

Comment: Hey psusi, meta-packages should of thought of that, I tried ubuntu-server but i it really dint help. The kind of problems im facing are i cant find sound card, can't resolve proxy and more i have to discover. Can you think of something more aggressive ?

Comment: @praneethmendu, nope... the desktop packages should include everything you need... I've used that method to build up a newly installed minimal command line system from the mini iso or `debootstrap`.